# time_bucket function to bucket on 24 hours with timezone where timezone is epoch milliseconds

Tags: timescaledb

I have a use-case where I am using TimescaleDb time_bucket function to rollup on daily level and my time column in epoch milliseconds.
It works fine but interval is split as per UTC start of day. I would like to pass my local time zone here.

Query for reference:

```
select time_bucket (, start_time) as interval,
SUM(metric_value) as value, ? as metricName,
first(start_time, start_time) as startTime, last(end_time, start_time) as endTime
from health_metric
where metric_name = ? and start_time >= ? and end_time <= ?
and user_id = ? group by interval order by interval
```